# Save and retrieve checkbox values asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to asp.net mvc and currently using MVC 2. I'm struggling with working with checkboxes for days now. I simply need to get checked checkbox values to be saved in database and on Edit view check them back.

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="coduit for safety near motor" name="Prepration" value="coduit for safety near motor"/><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="coduit for far side safety" name="Prepration" value="coduit for far side safety"/><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="coduit for power cable to near power point" name="Prepration" value="coduit for power cable to near power point"/><br />
```

On post controller method i can save the values of checked Checkboxes to the database as a comma separated string by using

strign a= = Request.Form["Prepration"];

How can i show them back on Edit view?

I don't know whether this is the way to do this any alternative solution would be great

Answer (score 1):

The answer of your first question:

**Need to get checked checkbox values to be saved in database**

On a button click push all the values in a array and from there store them in a hidden field and when you post your form get those values from this hidden field:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("input#btnSubmit").click(function () {
         var id = [];
         $("input[name='Prepration']:checked").each(function () {
         id.push($(this).val());
    });
    $("#HiddenFieldId").val(id);
         });
    });
    </script>
```

Now coming to your second question:

**How can i show them back on Edit view?**

```
<input type="radio" id="a" name="Prepration" checked="@Model.BoolPropertyName" />
```

Here you can have the value of in boolan.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can client side solution,

```
var data="";
$.each($("input:checkbox"),function(){
    if($(this).is("checked")){
        data+= $(this).val();
    }
});

// post here
```